# Redirect 2 domains to a landing page, then allow user to select which domain to visit

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've got a client who has two sites... - they are almost the same with minor differences (logo being the most obvious). Now he wants both domains to go to a landing page (that I've already set up and then from that landing page, the user can click to navigate to either site without being redirected again to the landing page.

I am kind of stumped on the best way to set that up.

Comment: Ask your client how they imagine it would work. What happens when you leave the landing page? Would you be sent back to the landing page? That is basically what you are describing here. You have to know these things before creating a question here.

Comment: I think it's obvious that it should not loop back to the landing page, but allow full access to the site chosen.

Answer (score -1):

Cookies/session and `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` are your friends.

Now you can use those as follow:

Whenever the user navigates one of the 2 domains you need to check for a session/cookie (that you set) to make sure they have visited the landing page. If that session/cookie doesn't exist, you can check for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` if it matches the landing page. If it matches, then set the session/cookie that the user has visited the landing page and any further navigation inside the domain will work since the session/cookie is now set.
If `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` doesn't match the landing page you redirect the user to the landing page and wait for them to come to one of the domains from that page in order to set the session/cookie.

I believe now you have all the info on what you need to do. The implementation part is all yours. That's what you're paid for right?

Comment: You could call on a lot of friends... This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, yes it is, I just needed to be pointed in the right direction.  Thank you, will try and let you know the result.  Curious also to know what effect this would have on the page load time?

Comment: Processing time is negligible.

Comment: There is no bullet-proof way to this, as anyone can clear their cache, cookies, private session and so on. Referrer is not always sent, IP will nullify others that haven't seen it yet, and so forth, even if you store some data to the users browser it can be cleared.